# Ansible run install command with prompts

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use ansible to automate my workstation install process. I am finding that I cannot get ansible to install doom emacs. It fails either with sending the two yes prompts yes or even fails sending the install command to doom.

```yaml
 - name: Install Doom Emacs
   expect:
     command: bash -c "~/.emacs.d/bin/doom install"
     responses:
        'Generate an envvar file? \(see `doom help env` for details\) (y or n)': 'y'
        "Download and install all-the-icon's fonts? (y or n)": 'y'
```

Would trying to get this to install just be a small niche problem that can't be solved with ansible?

Edit: This is with ansible core 2.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one immediate problem here: the [default `timeout`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html#parameter-timeout) for the `expect` module is 30 seconds. On my system, the install (timed by running `time ~/.emacs.d/bin/doom install`) takes around 2 minutes 30 seconds. Even if you expect/send configuration is correct, your task is going to timeout before the install is complete. Try something like:

```
 - name: Install Doom Emacs
   expect:
     command: bash -c "~/.emacs.d/bin/doom install"
     timeout: 300
     responses:
        'Generate an envvar file? \(see `doom help env` for details\) (y or n)': 'y'
        "Download and install all-the-icon's fonts? (y or n)": 'y'
```

Secondly, I had a hard time trying to get the underlying `pexpect` module to successfully match `Generate an envvar file? (see` doom help env`for details) (y or n)`. Rather than spending any more time on that problem, we can just match a substring, giving us:

```
- name: Install Doom Emacs
  expect:
    command: bash -c "~/.emacs.d/bin/doom install"
    timeout: 300
    responses:
       "Generate an envvar file?": "y\n"
       "Download and install": "y\n"
```

Thirdly (he added, after the answer had already been accepted), you're not "pressing enter" after sending your response. That is, you have:

```
 responses:
    'Generate an envvar file? \(see `doom help env` for details\) (y or n)': 'y'
```

Which is like typing `y` and then never pressing return, so the installer waits forever at the prompt. I've modified both responses to send a newline (`\n`) after the `y`.

The above task runs successfully for me.

---

The fundamental problem here is that doom does not have a non-interactive install mode, which makes it difficult to automate with any tool. There is [an issue to add one](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/issues/4603), and it looks like author has [accepted that into an ongoing rewrite](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/issues/4273), but that rewrite issue has been open for almost two years so it's not clear anything is going to change in the near future.

Comment: This mostly worked for me, it did output a massive error. The last few lines are below.

```
  > Cloning edit-indirect...", "  - Checked out edit-indirect: f80f63822ffae78de38dbe72cacaeb1aaa96c732", "  > Building edit-indirect...", "  > Cloning evil-markdown...", "  - Checked out evil-markdown: 8e6cc68af83914b2fa9fd3a3b8472573dbcef477", "  > Building evil-markdown...", "  > Cloning org...", "  - Checked out org: 86c4635dba556da01c18f6896aa09bf05d67802b", "  > Building org...", "  > Cloning org-contrib..."]}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an error necessarily, unless Ansible indicated that the task failed. In that case, the easiest solution may be to `regiser` the output and then write it to a file for inspection.

Comment: Ansible did say it failed, I am rerunning it right now to see if it was somehow a fluke. If it fails I will check the ansible docs on how to output the failure to a text file.

Comment: Confirmed it worked, since I already had my doom config files I had to increase the timeout to 600 instead of 300. Thank you so much for the help!